# Need help with board / components recommendation

Tags: lcd, low-power

I'm trying to make a self-contained graphic playing system, and would like to have components or full PCBs suggestions. What I need is:

- Output to a small color LCD. Like 3 inches, 65K color, 640x480 for example. No touch screen. Can be smaller if that helps, but at least 2 inches and enough resolution for decent pictures.
- 2D video frame buffer able to handle at least 30fps
- Programmable via a graphics library if possible (i.e. SDL)
- Very low power: able to stay powered by a cellphone battery for at least 10 hours (including the LCD!). The battery will be charged by a small solar panel during the day.
- Enough memory for a few images + code to move them around.
- As cheap as possible of course! :) Planning to buy in batches of 50 or so.
- Desirable but not completely needed:

  - Webcam input and being able to do simple tracking with openFrameworks or similar
  - Video playing capabilities
  - Auto power on when it has enough current.

I need to know if making such a system at home with available off-the-shelf components is possible, and if so, suggestions about which chip(s) / fully assembled PCB would do the task, as well as which screen should I get.

This won't be a handheld / portable system so space is not an issue, but low power is.

Comment: Don't you think it's quite ambitious considering your starting point?

Comment: No. An entry-level smartphone can do all that. I basically need the same with no wireless, touchscreen and sound. I already have a working prototype out of a disassembled old Android device, but it's an overkill for what I have in mind and would prefer a more custom tailored system.

Comment: Yes, but unless you are Htc or Samsung, an entry-level smartphone is a quite complex system, and requires some sort of planning, before looking for pieces to put together, IMHO

Comment: I need to know if this is even viable given the low power + graphics requirement. My Android prototype can't stay powered for 10 hours on a 1000mAh battery with the screen on running a simple demo of sprites moving around, but my guess is that a custom tailored system would. But first I need to know if that system can even be built at home with off-the-shelf components, not only by HTC or Samsung. I'll edit my question to point that I would accept "it's not possible" as a good answer as well.

Comment: What I think is that putting all this things together requires expert designers (probably more than one), multi-layer PCBs, very low-power design, HW/SW integration and probably certification, if really you want to make at least 50 units. It's not what I would call an home project...

Comment: It's really simpler to buy and hack a smartphone

Comment: It's for an art project, will need about 50 units as each unit will feature different content. They will be enclosed in sturdy, sealed acrylic glass boxes and hanged in walls across the city, so that's why the low power as they need to run off solar power for a week (the exhibition's length), having nowhere to plug.

Comment: Will investigate into the cheapest smartphone that can fit my requirements then, if you really think a custom system is out of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Just to know, what is your background and\or the resources you have?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2286/discussion-between-mccoy-and-clabacchio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's doable.
You do need to say what you'd like it to cost (acceptable/target/dream)..

But by far the best way of doing it is to either remove or disable power consuming features from a smartphone or one of the many low cost Asian "pocket PCs" that have screen size from about 3" to 8".

Or, one of the many entry level Linux capable single board systems ("Gooseberry Pie" style (yes I know).)

---

- Output to a small color LCD. Like 3 inches, 65K color, 640x480 for example. No touch screen. Can be smaller if that helps, but at least 2 inches and enough resolution for decent pictures.

Buy module. Connect drive. Done

- 2D video frame buffer able to handle at least 30fps
  Programmable via a graphics library if possible (i.e. SDL)

Smartphone, ... . Yes.

- Very low power: able to stay powered by a cellphone battery for at least 10 hours (including the LCD!). The battery will be charged by a small solar panel during the day.

Deep-ends on what you want to run. If you ant video live all day long you will need to look very carefully at power budget.
 Take iPhone 3 as "cellphone battery". About 1300 mAh. 10 hours = 130 mA at 3.6V nominal ~= 470 mW. Say 400 to 500 mW. Backlight is out (50-100 mW per LED) except for short periods if essential.

Best way to see what can be done is to look at the state of the art consumer products. Most modern DSLRs have an LCD on the back of about the size and capability of what you describe.
 Sony are amongst the market leaders. As of August 2011 here is their latest offering.
 [Sony White Magic 3" VGA LCD display](http://www.sony.net/SonyInfo/News/Press/201108/11-086E/index.html)
 claimed to reduce power consumption by about 50% over previous devices. VGA RGBW, 3",
 225 mW low power mode 470 cd/m^2 with 125 mW backlight
 400 mW outdoor mode 1000 Cd/m^2 with 300 mW backlight.

SO Sony say 225 mW is indoor mode at 50% previous suggesting 400 mW+ previously.
 That's with backlight - if you can get it backlight free it's easier.

Note in the above specs the display proper draws 100 mW.

- Enough memory for a few images + code to move them around.

  Webcam input and being able to do simple tracking with openFrameworks or similar

  Video playing capabilities

  Auto power on when it has enough current.

Just do it.

---

Arduino plus various "shields".
 Smartphone with stuff hacked off.
 Asian mini tablet with not much hacked off.
 Gooseberry Pi plus what people will immediately add to it when it arrives.
 Buy modules and combine at much higher cost.

---

An obvious way to ease the spec is to accept the need for a higher capacity battery.

10 hours at 0.5W requires 2.5W PV panel in winter or 1 - 1.5 W in summer deep-ending where you are. More takes more.

Buying PV panels in 50 quantity you can get them at say 2W for $10 each. (ie $2.50 each ex factory in 1000s.)  That's not a major component in your pricing.

Much more could be said, but that should give a good guide.